# Email Template - Anchor tag styling removed on email forward

Tags: html, css, anchor, styling, email-templates

Issue: I am facing issue in persisting the styling on an anchor tag on forwarding the email.

I have tried the behaviour on cross-devices and cross-browser even cross-platform(Mac and Windows).

Below is the demo code I used for email template:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a
            href="http://helloworld.com"
            style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none;">
             Hello World
          </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Actual Result - All the styling are remove from anchor tag on forward.
Expected Result - All the styling should persist on anchor tag on forward.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XLOWJv

Comment: Hi @FrancescoMineo, it is an email template code piece. You can replicate the issue by using this piece as an email template to generate an email and forward it to any email client.

Comment: I can't test now... Try with !important, so: style="color:#000!important".
Otherwise use style tag at the begin of your template
<style>table>tbody>tr>td>a{color:#000; ... }</style>

Comment: I tried moving the styling on the td also using !important, no luck

Comment: How you send the email? Are you using native mail() function or other libraries like phpmailer?

Comment: I am using email-bootstrap ruby gem to transpile and send mail. It uses smtp underneath to send mail

Comment: Which email client is changing the code?

Comment: @Syfer, I guess all, I tried - Apple Mail, Outlook, Gmail.